# MySQL grouping with a comma separated field

Tags: mysql

Here's a tricky one.

I have data as follows:

```
User ID  Name     Skill Sets
1        Jim      Install, Configure
2        Jack     Install
3        John     Configure, Setup, Blah
4        Bill     Setup, Install
```

This isn't my design, and it's not an option to change the way the data is formatted.  The trouble is that I need to group by the unique skill sets.  Obviously a group by right now gives me:

```
Skill Set                Count
Install, Configure       1
Install                  1
Configure, Setup, Blah   1
Setup, Install           1
```

Desired Output is:

```
Skill Set    Count
Install      3
Configure    2
Setup        2
Blah         1
```

Any Ideas? I could conceivably make a view that separates the skill sets into a normalized form (as it should be).  But I'm not positive on the syntax for that either.

Comment: Is the set of possible skills well defined, or do you have to go by "whatever appears anywhere in a skill set field"?

Comment: The skills are well defined in a separate table.  They just chose to concatenate the string instead of using a proper relational table.  The data is shit, of course, because there were typos in some skill names that were changed.  I can accept having "Install" and "Instla" as separate groups though for now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to have a rowset containing all possible values of your skills.

`MySQL` lacks a way to do it, so you'll have to generate it somehow.

If you have such a resultset, just issue:

```
SELECT  skill, COUNT(*)
FROM    (
        SELECT 'Install' AS skill
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'Configure' AS skill
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'Setup' AS skill
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'Blah' AS skill
        ) s
JOIN    users u
ON      find_in_set(s.skill, u.sets)
GROUP BY
        s.skill
```

Since you mentioned that you have your skills in a separate table, use that table:

```
SELECT  skill, COUNT(*)
FROM    skills s
JOIN    users u
ON      find_in_set(s.skill, u.sets)
GROUP BY
        s.skill
```

This, however, will not ever match the typos, they will be just skipped.

Comment: At first glance it looks like this will give me the number of skills that each user has, as opposed to the number of users that each skill has. Still, the concept is the same (I think).  I'll give this a shot.

Comment: Works great, thanks Quassnoi!  the "find_in_set" was the missing link for me.