# Mysql - How to query a table that may have multiple entries in each cell and get a result with single values in each cell

Tags: php, mysql

```
Name       Hobby
John    |  Fishing,Traveling
Mary    |  Reading,
Tom     |  Music,
Kate    |  Cooking,Reading
George  |  Traveling,
Peter   |  Fishing,
Lisa    |  Cooking,
```

I want to select this table

```
Hobby        Count
Fishing   |  2
Traveling |  2
Reading   |  2
Music     |  1
Cooking   |  2
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Found nearly a duplicate, with an interesting answer from Quassnoi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951357/mysql-grouping-with-a-comma-separated-field - However I 100% agree with others for normalizing the schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like @Wes

or if its not possible i'd do it in PHP

```
$result = array();
$sql = 'SELECT Hobby, count(*) as cnt FROM youttable GROUP BY Hobby';
foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
    foreach(explode(',',$row['Hobby']) as $hobby) {
        $result[$hobby] += $row['cnt'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use your table properly instead of cramming multiple hobby values into a single column.  You should have:

```
John    |  Fishing
John    |  Traveling
Mary    |  Reading
Tom     |  Music
Kate    |  Cooking
Kate    |  Reading
George  |  Traveling
Peter   |  Fishing
Lisa    |  Cooking
```

Then you can do:

```
select hobby
     , count(*) count
  from tablename
 group by hobby
 order by hobby
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the table structure. Is there a way to make this query in my existing table ? thanx

Answer (score 0):

Generally what you would do is have a separate table for hobbies.
So your first table would be consisted of: nameID, name.
And your second table would consist of: hobbyID, nameID, description.
Once you have it set up like that, you use nameID to link the two tables together.

```
SELECT * FROM nameTable, hobbyTable WHERE nameTable.nameID = hobbyTable.nameID
```

And when you have that you can use count() on the hobbyTable to get the quantities.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT Hobby, Count(*) FROM myTable ORDER BY Hobby GROUP BY Hobby
```

Comment: This won't work with the table structure that was presented in the original question.

Comment: That will not work with the present form of the data.  If the data were correct then your query would be correct.  His problem is having multiple values store in a single column.

Comment: I posted this before the original post was reformatted and it became apparent that each person could have more than one Hobby. This table design is really bad - it should be normalized.